# How to resolve "integrity errors" revealed by "hg verify"

Tags: mercurial, corruption, verify

I have a shared repository for which `hg verify` reveals seven problems attributable to a very old changeset (@2445).

Having failed to repair the repository as described
in detail below, I would greatly appreciate
any advice about repairing it.

Please note that I have successfully used "hg convert" to create a new repository which passes the `hg verify` test, but of course the revision
hashes are all different, so this is not really a solution for the
"corrupt" repository that is on bitbucket and that others have cloned.

#### Problem Description

The repository on bitbucket has been cloned to two machines, one
running hg 4.7.2, and the other running hg 5.0.1.

The clone on the hg 4.7.2 machine never exhibited any overt problems,
but the upgrade to hg 5.0.1 on the other led me to run "hg verify",
which reveals the same 7 errors on both machines.

(On the hg 5.0.1 machine, additional issues involving "fncache" are identified but they go beyond the scope of this question.)

The 7 errors are identified in the section of the "hg verify"
output beginning:

```
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
```

The first error message is:

```
MI/MI_s15/all/done@2445: dbb0190415fa not in manifests
```

and all the others refer to the same local rev "@2445".

The final line of the output of "hg verify" is:

```
(first damaged changeset appears to be 2445)
```

#### Attempted Repairs

The following attempts all failed to fix these problems:

a) hg debugrebuildstate -r tip

b) hg debugrebuildfncache # failed with the explanation: "(not rebuilding fncache because repository does not support fncache)"

c) In a new directory on the hg 5.0.1 machine, cloning the repository from its home on bitbucket did not help.

d) In the newly cloned repo created in (c) above:

```
hg strip --rev 2444
hg pull -u
# `hg verify` shows the same 7 errors
hg debugrebuildfncache # now succeeds
# `hg verify` shows the same 7 errors
```

Similar attempts likewise failed.

### debugindex

In case it helps:

```
   $ hg debugindex MI/MI_s15/all/done
   rev linkrev nodeid       p1           p2
     0    1337 b5d33daadd43 000000000000 000000000000
     1    2445 dbb0190415fa 000000000000 000000000000
```

Comment: Do you recognise that file name? The error message is saying that there is a log of revisions for a file that cannot be found in your manifest of files. This usually happens due to a botched strip operation. I think simply removing the offending file log from `.hg/store/data` might work. Try that on a fresh clone.

Comment: @JordiGutiérrezHermoso - Thanks for your suggestion, but could you be more specific about what I should do?  Are you suggesting that I remove the ".i" files such as .hg/store/data/_m_i/mi__s15/all/done.i ?  Doing so just adds to the number of errors found....

Comment: That's what I meant. But I misunderstood what's going on here.

The error means that a filelog (those .i files) contains a hash to identify the revisions of this file, along with a revision number of a commit, which is not found in the manifestlog (a list for each commit that says at which revision each file is) does not have.

So there basically is an unreferenced revision for that file.

Comment: Looking at `hg debugindex MI/MI_s15/all/done` as well as `hg debugindex --manifest` and `hg debugindex --changelog`. It probably won't help with your problem but it should explain what I'm talking about. Mercurial is built out of three kind revlogs which are the changelog, the manifest, and filelogs. The latter two have a linkrev that says which changelog entry (ordinary commit revision) they correspond to. The problem is you have a filelog with a revision that does not appear in the manifest.